# Manipulating database rows with UDJC in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: database, pentaho, kettle

I want to get rows from the database and then apply some java code on each row.
How do I get a single row for manipulating in User Defined Java Class step?

If someone can elucidate this scenario with an example would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are samples in $KETTLE_HOME/samples directory. It includes as well example of using UserDefinedJavaClass Step.

Comment: Thank you so much. The example helped me.

Comment: Some insights, it support java6 only. Hard to implement complex logic since debugging not available(but possible to use System.out.println). In case of any error NullPointerException thrown without any problem description.